Error:Deploying program failed transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: account data too small for instruction [3 log messages]
Getting this error white deploying the program on devnet using anchor deploy. I am writing the program for minting the tokens:-
Recover the intermediate account's ephemeral keypair file with
solana-keygen recover and the following 12-word seed phrase:
shadow ship foam shop side aisle feel congress long dash what exercise
To resume a deploy, pass the recovered keypair as the
[BUFFER_SIGNER] to solana program deploy or solana program write-buffer'. Or to recover the account's lamports, pass it as the [BUFFER_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS] argument to solana program close`.
Error: Deploying program failed: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: account data too small for instruction [3 log messages]
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
#![allow(clippy::result_large_err)]

use {
    anchor_lang::prelude::*,
    anchor_spl::{
        associated_token::AssociatedToken,
        metadata::{
            create_metadata_accounts_v3, mpl_token_metadata::types::DataV2,
            CreateMetadataAccountsV3, Metadata,
        },
        token::{mint_to, Mint, MintTo, Token, TokenAccount},
    },
};
declare_id!("6SoLn7evYbz9YPHCyh5CsVifCax3WhZwUFoc9Vyaoqoi");

#[program]
pub mod marketplace {
    use super::*;

    pub fn mint_nft(
        ctx: Context<CreateToken>,
        nft_name: String,
        nft_symbol: String,
        nft_uri: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Minting Tokens");

        mint_to(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                MintTo {
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.associated_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            1,
        )?;

        msg!("Creating metadata account");

        create_metadata_accounts_v3(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
                CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
                    metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata_account.to_account_info(),
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                    mint_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    update_authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                    rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            DataV2 {
                name: nft_name,
                symbol: nft_symbol,
                uri: nft_uri,
                seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
                creators: None,
                collection: None,
                uses: None,
            },
            false,
            true,
            None,
        )?;

        msg!("NFT minted successfully");

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateToken<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: Validate address by deriving pda
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"metadata", token_metadata_program.key().as_ref(), mint_account.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        seeds::program = token_metadata_program.key(),
    )]
    pub metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = payer.key(),
        mint::freeze_authority = payer.key(),
    )]
    pub mint_account: Account<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer,
        associated_token::mint = mint_account,
        associated_token::authority = payer,
    )]
    pub associated_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub token_metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}


You will need to extend your program size, if you made changes to it.  This is possible from the CLI version 1.18 >
To fix this run
solana program extend PROGRAM_ADDRESS_HERE 20000 -u d -k ~/.config/solana/id.json

The command above will increase your program by 20000 bytes and use using the keypair at ~/.config/solana/id.json

It worked. Thank you for your response.
